# Google Guava cache pass extra parameters to load/loadAll

Tags: java, caching, design-patterns, guava

I have a

```
LoadingCache<Long, String> idNameMap
```

that needs to be populated. The ids are unique in the context of my application. However, due to the way data is stored in the table, I need to pass in extra parameters to database query to complete a fast database lookup. Which means that I should be able to pass these parameters to my loadAll method which currently looks like:

```
@Override
public Map<Long, String> loadAll(Iterable idsIterable) throws Exception {
    //pass in ids and extra parameters to improve database query speed
}
```

Those extra parameters do not need to be part of my cache. My question is that what pattern should I use to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you make the parameters member variables in your CacheLoader?

Comment: The parameters would be different for each fetch from the cache. I am not sure how would I pass them. Could you show me an example snippet?

Comment: Not really, I'm unclear on your requirements - can you give an example of the parameters, and why they are different from each fetch from the cache.

Comment: Think about it like this. I am trying to cache SSN - First Name mappings for entire population of US. We know for sure that SSN is unique. So therefore the cache will be LoadingCache<Long, String> idNameMap. However, the database table that contains this information is not indexed by SSN. Instead, its indexed by City name or something more granular. So to speed up the database lookup, I need to pass in the City name each time as well. Makes sense?

Actually I solved this problem by creating a new index on my table on the id field. So this way I do not need to pass in the extra parameters.

Comment: Well, you presumably need to know the city when you call the get method, if you're going to use that in the event of a cache miss. You can make the key `Pair<Long, String>` (or, better, a semantically specific key class like `SsnWithCity`). The obvious downside of that is that you will store an extra reference per key. Instead, you could call `getIfPresent`, and then look up the values in bulk if it's not found (and have to deal with the synchronization issues yourself...).

Comment: I agree with Andy, you should be caching using the keys necessary to compute the values. Uniqueness is not the primary constraint. It's possible you shouldn't be using a `LoadingCache` at all. Or perhaps you should have another cache of SSN's to City names which you then reference from your SSN->FirstName loader.

Comment: We have a similar issue -- we don't want to put it all in the keys because we call this 50x/second and that is a huge number of generated objects (and the original key we already have)